# Fonts glyphcons missing using yeoman generator

Tags: gulp, yeoman, meanjs, glyphicons

I'm using for the first time Yeoman, and I installed a generator called gulp-angular, where I have components like bootstrap-sass, but I'm having an issue, when I run `gulp-serve` it gives me an error:

```
http://localhost:3000/bootstrap-sass/assets/fonts/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://localhost:3000/bootstrap-sass/assets/fonts/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://localhost:3000/bootstrap-sass/assets/fonts/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

I can't figure out why this is happening. I checked inside bower and I see the files there. I tried using `gulp fonts`, but the fonts are still missing.

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same issue and found that the `$icon-font-path` was pointing to the wrong directory in the `index.scss` file

this line: 
`$icon-font-path: "../../bootstrap-sass/assets/fonts/bootstrap/";`

should be: 
`$icon-font-path: "../../bower_components/bootstrap-sass/assets/fonts/bootstrap/";`

Hope that helps